# Delete input.value when key is pressed

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML input on my page. The user is able to type text into it. When he types in a command, that I specified, and presses enter, the page outputs information into the `input.value`. If the user types in something random and confirms his input, the page just outputs: "Unknown command.", again into to `input.value`.

I made a striped down Fiddle here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_R/m1or79wn/)

**The Problem**:
When I type in: `test` and press enter, the value changes to: `This is kind of working…`. I know want to type in something new, but I first have to highlight, or delete the `This is kind of working…` text, which is really not intuitive.

Is there a way to change my script, so that when I'm in the input and I press any button, that is not button Nr.13 aka "Enter", the page just makes the value of the input, the button, that has been pressed? So that the user can just start typing in something new, after receiveing a value and doesn't have to delete the value that I put in there.

I tried adding an additional .onkeypress function, but it destroyed everything, so I didn't do it the right way.

This is my current JS:

```
var clInput = 0;

document.querySelector("#inputMain").onkeypress = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '13'){
        clInput =  document.querySelector("#inputMain").value;

        switch (clInput) {
            case "test":
                test();
            break;

            default:
                document.querySelector("#inputMain").value = "Unknown command.";
        }
    return false;
    }
  }

function test() {
    document.querySelector("#inputMain").value = "This is kind of working…";
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="inputMain" name="inputMain" autofocus>
```

Comment: Just set the `placeholder` on the input, and empty out the value.

Comment: I already got an answer that works, but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code a bit to do exactly what you want. What was essentially done was to:

1. Keep track of when you pressed `13 - Enter`.
2. Then if `13 - Enter` was previously pressed, just make sure to clear the input.

You can check the demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/nh6c7ugf/

```
var clInput = 0; // Note: Ignore Upper- / Lower-Case in input?
var isEntered = false;

document.querySelector("#inputMain").onkeypress = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;

    // clear the value
    if (isEntered) {
      isEntered = false;
      document.querySelector("#inputMain").value = '';
    }

    if (e.keyCode == '13'){
        clInput =  document.querySelector("#inputMain").value;
        isEntered = true;

        switch (clInput) {
            case "test":
                test();
                break;

            default:
                document.querySelector("#inputMain").value = "Unknown command.";
        }

        return false;
    }
}

function test() {
    document.querySelector("#inputMain").value = "This is kind of working…";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I don't understand what you are trying to say 
but if you want that the user can just start typing in something new, after receiving value and doesn't have to delete the value that you put in there.
you can do

```
function test() {
    document.querySelector("#inputMain").value = "This is kind of working…";
    document.querySelector("#inputMain").selct();

}
```

This will select all the text of the input field and when the user will type something the previous value of the field will be deleted